# How to plot a straight horizontal line based on the highest high of the latest 'n' candles?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

I'd like to plot a straight horizontal line at the highest of the latest 'n' candles. NOT based on the highest of 'n' candles ago, but the highest of all these 'n' candles. Please, check the screenshot.

I understand the plots start in the past and change when something happens "in the future", but since the data is all there I suppose this logic could also be achieved.

The below is the usual 'highesthigh' code, but of course it won't work for this.

```
n=72
highestHigh = highest(high, n)
plot(highestHigh)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study("Help (line back)", overlay=true)

bars_back=input(5,"Bars back")
n        =input(10, "High back")

highestHigh = highest(high, n)
line.new(bar_index-bars_back, highestHigh, bar_index, highestHigh, extend=extend.none) // draws a line to the next high
```

Comment: It is difficult to see the room through the keyhole.
So I didn't understand your question.